# How to define common test in a module file and then include it in the minitest class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have defined a test that is common for multiple app in common/signin_test.rb as follow:

```
module Common
  test "Sign in page test" do
    visit '/'
    assert true
  end
end
```

And I have created a minitest in different file as follow:

```
require '../common/signin_test'

module App1
  class SigninTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    include Common
  end
end
```

when I run the test it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught exception: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
    signin_test.rb:2:in `test'
```

Comment: Maybe its just the example that is strange but I can't really see the point. Why would you want all your test classes to run the exact same test?

Comment: I got 3 apps and the test suite for each app is in different folder. There are some common test like sign in/out. So I want to create a shared module that define those test and run them separately with each test suite.

Comment: OK, the following link solve the problem http://schock.net/articles/2015/01/21/modules-with-rails-tests-share-behavior-minitest/
but now I am getting different error: `Minitest::UnexpectedError: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: $ is not defined`

Comment: The problem been solve using above link